# How to pass form data to an external API in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am designing an online application that uses mobile money as a means of payment. But I need assistance on how I can pass my order form data to the API of the mobile money service providers who complete the transaction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should supply some more information to make your question answerable. What have you tried, how are you communicating with the API (e.g. through an existing gem)? Please see the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to write a good question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try httparty, post method.

An existed example could be

```
options = {:type => auto}
payload = options.to_json
query = {
  :request_id => request_id,
  ......................
  :user_id => user
}
response = post("/tbc/submit_job.json", :body => payload, :query => query)
```

You can use httparty to customize yours.